# Getting a js error when i am trying to open appium desktop

Tags: appium-desktop

I have just downloaded Appium-Server-GUI-mac-1.22.3.dmg but when I try to open it a JS error message is displayed. I also ran the following in the terminal xattr -cr /Applications/Appium\ Server\ GUI.app but still seeing the same issue when I try to open the app. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXKo8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this doc on the official doc .It has similar issue listed .

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#installing-on-macos